# Apache Location regex is not matching paths

Tags: node.js, apache, express, routes

I'm just trying to point my apache server at a node.js app by changing the virtual host settings to use proxy settings and when I try to make the  Block match all locations via  It matches only urls with 1 level deep url paths. /example works but /example/damn does not work. So I tried changing the regex to  Which is even overkill but I thought I'd try it, I've been trying a lot of other regex combinations but none capture the URLs. I might add that this regex above actually doesn't capture anything AT ALL, it just shows the index list for my site when I got the url. The only regex that works at all is "/*" but it doesn't go deeper than 1 url /path/anotherpath

I checked that my regex should be matching everything at https://regex101.com/ But still apache isn't capturing it.

here's me config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName my.dev
        ServerAdmin ireply@myleisure.com.au
        DocumentRoot /home/ggg/Dropbox/host-root/var/www/myleisure.com.au

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyVia Full

        <Proxy "*">
                Require all granted
        </Proxy>

        <Location "(.*)*">
                ProxyPass http://localhost:3000
                ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000
        </Location>



</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is quote from Apache directive configuration [documentation page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#locationmatch)

> The  directive limits the scope of the enclosed
>   directives by URL, in an identical manner to . However, it
>   takes a regular expression as an argument instead of a simple string.

Therefore, try using:

```
<LocationMatch "(.*)*">
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3000
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: </LocationMatch> But thank you so much. I'm still realising that I need to read documentation. But in my opinion I don't want to take the chance that I simply miss something or don't realise something in the documentation so I would rather see if someone has had the same problem. I'm guessing you just read the documentation though. It's a skill I need to work on. 

Thank you very much Nomad